# Scipy euclidean and minkowski gave same result

Tags: python, scipy

When i tried minkowski and euclidean distance from scipy, i got the same results,

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
dst1= distance.euclidean(input1, input2)
dst2= distance.minkowski(input1, input2)
print(dst1==dst2)
```

If i checked the code, the euclidean function is calling minkowski. [Github link](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/b5d8bab88af61d61de09641243848df63380a67f/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L492-L528)
Why is this so?

Answer (score 2):

The [Minkowski distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_distance) has a parameter `p`.  The Euclidean distance is a special case of Minkowski distance, with `p = 2`.

The default value of `p` for [`scipy.distance.minkowski`](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.minkowski.html) is `p = 2`, so if you don't specify `p`, `minkowski` computes the  Euclidean distance.